# Meaning of "I'd say tomorrow."

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

Consider:

> Got 3000 words to write this morning before racing north to Edinburgh
>   for the BBC Q&A for new writers at the Filmhouse this afternoon.
>   Speakers include the BBC's Creative Director of New Writing Kate
>   Rowland [pictured] and River City executive producer Sandra MacIver. I
>   plan to take copious notes and will hopefully share some of those here
>   in the next few days. **I'd say tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines
>   to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.
>
> [--source](http://viciousimagery.blogspot.jp/2006_08_01_archive.html)

I'm wondering what's the meaning of "I'd say tomorrow."

Comment: Context is important to answer these kind of questions. While I have a suspicion, we need to know more to say for sure. Please [tell us where you heard or read this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1084/1797)!

Comment: Thank you　for your comment, Eric.
I happened to read some internet post by female editor.
She wrote as follows; Got 3000 words to write this morning before racing north to Edinburgh for the BBC Q&A for new writers at the Filmhouse this afternoon. Speakers include the BBC's Creative Director of New Writing Kate Rowland [pictured] and River City executive producer Sandra MacIver. I plan to take copious notes and will hopefully share some of those here in the next few days. **I'd say tomorrow,** but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones. Besides,...

Comment: Link is here; http://viciousimagery.blogspot.jp/2006_08_01_archive.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to reiterate your context:

> Got 3000 words to write this morning before racing north to Edinburgh for the BBC Q&A for new writers at the Filmhouse this afternoon. Speakers include the BBC's Creative Director of New Writing Kate Rowland [pictured] and River City executive producer Sandra MacIver. I plan to take copious notes and will hopefully share some of those here in the next few days. **I'd say tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.

Here, the author wishes to share her notes with her readers in the upcoming days. However, she's very busy, and doesn't want to impose a deadline on herself. In this sense, her phrase essentially means that she'd like to promise us a date, but can't because of her other deadlines. Something like this:

> **I wish I could promise you that I would share the notes tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.

You can then reduce this unnecessarily long phrase as necessary:

> **I wish I could tell you that I would share the notes tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.
>
> **I wish I could say that I would share the notes tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.
>
> **I wish I could say tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.
>
> **I would say tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.
>
> **I'd say tomorrow**, but I've got enough deadlines to contend with at the moment without inventing new ones.

All of these have the same meaning.

Comment: Eric, thank you so much for your explanation. I’ve got clear understanding of what’s the meaning of the phrase.
At the same time, so amazed　at the high quality of this site’s Q & A, of course including your answer this time. Again, thank you for your patience with my awkward question.

Comment: @KayT No problem, glad I could help! If I answered your question though, click the check mark next to my answer (just to mark the question as solved). :)

Comment: Plz don't urge OP to check the mark too soon even if it's a good answer. OP should wait for a few hours to see any other possible comments or answers. @KayT

Comment: @Zhanlong Zheng, sorry for my ignorance of these rules.
Next time, I'll comply with the procedures for sure.